# Puppet server cannot be changed from 'stopped' to 'running'

Tags: puppet

I have two ubuntu 14.04 servers running puppet in a private openstack cloud:

1. A master running puppetserver and puppetmaster (packages: puppet-agent, puppetserver, puppet-common, puppetmaster-common)
2. And a client (packages: puppet-agent, puppet-common)

Both servers have entries for each other and themselves in the `/etc/hosts` file, the entry for my master is named `puppet`.

My puppet server cannot be changed from 'stopped' to 'running'.  Here is the output of the command normally used to change this value:

```
myUsername@puppet:~$ puppet resource service puppetserver ensure=running
Notice: /Service[puppetserver]/ensure: ensure changed 'stopped' to 'running'
service { 'puppetserver':
  ensure => 'stopped',
}
```

Due to this nothing can connect to my puppet server and all attempts result in the following output (no matter if I run the command from the puppet client or master):

```
myUsername@puppetclient:~$ puppet agent --test
Error: Could not request certificate: Connection refused - connect(2)
Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled
```

I also noticed that I cannot restart the puppetserver service:

```
myUsername@puppet-3949:/etc/puppet/manifests$ sudo service puppetserver restart
/etc/init.d/puppetserver: 69: /etc/init.d/puppetserver: wait_for_pidfile: not found
   ...fail!
start-stop-daemon: unable to chdir() to /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver (No such file or directory)
```

Additionally running the command `sudo netstat -nap | grep 8140` has no output.  So in conclusion my puppet server is not running and cannot be started by conventional means.  What is another method of starting my puppetserver?  Or how can I change my configuration to allow for puppet to be started through conventional means?

Comment: To be honest, I would recommend not having your puppetmaster in the cloud. I have attached openstack instances to a puppetmaster running on virtual machines and it worked great, but I have had all kinds of issues attaching openstack instances to a master on another openstack instance, and this was using Puppet Enterprise even.

Comment: Nope I had the same exact problem running it in a vagrant box.

Comment: @AlexCohen What does the puppetserver log indicate?